# PHP variable in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, variables, loops, foreach

I am trying to use a variable in a foreach loop but I am getting strange results. The first foreach loop work fine but gives a notice of a undefined variable and in the second version there is no notice but it only returns the last item in the array.

```
$formats = array(
    'application/x-mpegurl' => 'hls',
    'video/webm'            => 'webm',
    'video/mp4'             => 'mp4',
    'video/ogg'             => 'ogg',
    'video/flash'           => 'flash',
);

// Works perfectly but there a undefined variable $source
foreach( $formats as $format => $src ){
    if ( !empty( $src ) ) {
        $source .= '<source type="' . $format . '" src="' . $src . '">';
    }
}
echo $source;

// Returns only the last item in the variable but there is no undefined variable
foreach( $formats as $format => $src ){
    $source2 = '';
    if ( !empty( $src ) ) {
        $source2 .= '<source type="' . $format . '" src="' . $src . '">';
    }
}
echo $source2;
```

I have googled for solutions have not found any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `$source` an d `$source1` before the loops start.

```
 $source = "";
 // loop starts here
```

Complete code:

```
$source = "";
foreach( $formats as $format => $src ){
   if ( !empty( $src ) ) {
     $source .= '<source type="' . $format . '" src="' . $src . '">';
   }
}
echo $source;

$source2 = '';
foreach( $formats as $format => $src ){
   if ( !empty( $src ) ) {
      $source2 .= '<source type="' . $format . '" src="' . $src . '">';
   }
}
echo $source2;
```

Comment: Do you know why it must be pre-defined before the loop? seems weird to me that it almost acts like a variable scope issue.

Comment: Not the variable scope issue but on each iteration he was setting the blank value to the variable

Answer (score 2):

In both cases the variables need to be defined outside the foreach loop:

```
$formats = array(
    'application/x-mpegurl' => 'hls',
    'video/webm'            => 'webm',
    'video/mp4'             => 'mp4',
    'video/ogg'             => 'ogg',
    'video/flash'           => 'flash',
);

// Works perfectly but there a undefined variable $source
$source = '';
foreach( $formats as $format => $src ){
    if ( !empty( $src ) ) {
        $source .= '<source type="' . $format . '" src="' . $src . '">';
    }
}
echo $source;

// Returns only the last item in the variable but there is no undefined variable
$source2 = '';
foreach( $formats as $format => $src ){
    if ( !empty( $src ) ) {
        $source2 .= '<source type="' . $format . '" src="' . $src . '">';
    }
}
echo $source2;
```

Answer (score 2):

First problem

- Need to define the $source variable outside the loop.

Second issue

- Pretty similar to first u need to define the variable outside the loop and then concate
  inside the loop. You are doing inside the loop which is why its getting over-written and getting the last value.

  ```
  $source = '';

  foreach( $formats as $format => $src ){
      if ( !empty( $src ) ) {
          $source .= '<source type="' . $format . '" src="' . $src . '">';
      }
  }
  echo $source;
  $source2 = '';
  // Returns only the last item in the variable but there is no undefined variable
  foreach( $formats as $format => $src ){

      if ( !empty( $src ) ) {
          $source2 .= '<source type="' . $format . '" src="' . $src . '">';
      }
  }
  echo $source2;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The first message `undefined variable $source` means that the variable named `$source` has not been defined yet. The code will work without defining the variable source, but it's not the way to go ;)

> Although PHP does not require variable declaration, it does recommend
>   it in order to avoid some security vulnerabilities or bugs where one
>   would forget to give a value to a variable that he will use later in
>   the script. What PHP does in the case of undeclared variables is issue
>   a very low level error, E_NOTICE, one that is not even reported by
>   default, but the Manual advises to allow during development.

([PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index))

As for your second problem.. You're redefining `$source2` every iteration of the loop. Simply move `$source2` so that it is defined on the line above the `foreach`.

```
// Returns only the last item in the variable but there is no undefined variable
$source2 = '';  // MOVED THIS LINE
foreach( $formats as $format => $src ){    
    if ( !empty( $src ) ) {
        $source2 .= '<source type="' . $format . '" src="' . $src . '">';
    }
}
```

Read more on defining variables in the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php